# C# Application, Cookies not set when we open application through iFrame tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created one web application and when i run application in normal browser windows it works perfectly. But when i open same application in iFrame tag my cookies get vanished automatically.

When I Inspect browser window i can see the cookies and session but it won't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbZDo.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have not set the domain on the web.config

Some times you call the iframe with out the `www.` on your domain, and this is set a different cookie than when you have the `www.`

so on `web.config` set the `domain` where its needed, eg:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="local.com" />
</authentication>

<httpCookies domain="local.com" />
```

Comment: I have added below config in web.config file

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="500" cookieSameSite="None"/> 
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" domain="local.com"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Auth" timeout="500" slidingExpiration="true" domain="local.com"/> 
        </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

```
I have added below config in web.config file 

 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="500" cookieSameSite="None"/> 
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" domain="local.com"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Auth" timeout="500" slidingExpiration="true" domain="local.com"/> 
        </authentication>

But still cookies not set. Could you please assist?
```

Comment: do you use the `local.com` on the url ? (set the local.com on `host` file etc...)